# Javascript symbol about "if" statement

Tags: javascript

I got an "if" statement and i want to check if one textcontent of the variable is different from A or from B
but this doesnt seem to work
Any suggestion ??

```
if ( el[0].textContent !=  "A" || "B")
```

Comment: `el[0].textContent !=  "A" || el[0].textContent !=  "B"` but this will always be `true`. What you need is `&&` instead.

Comment: ^ There's that, if the text is **not** `A` **OR not** `B` is always true, it's always **not** one of them !

Comment: Yes, so use AND then

Comment: i want it always to be true ! Its only checking the language of one code.

Comment: Then just drop the if statement ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a basic syntax error.

Comment: Then why use an `if` statement if there is no condition?

Comment: Regex is best solution  - `if (el[0].textContent.match(/^[AB]$/) {`

Comment: @Elad there is a semantically more correct `.test` method. PS: I would not call it "the best" either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ( el[0].textContent !=  "A" || el[0].textContent !=  "B")

if ( el[0].textContent != "A" && el[0].textContent != "B")
```

2nd solution from Phil_1984_

Check this out.
You have to declare to your variable both of the "things" you need to check.
and after this you will have the result you want.

Comment: Optimize it with `if (true)`, which in turn can be simply removed from the code.

Comment: OP really means if ( el[0].textContent !=  "A" && el[0].textContent !=  "B")

Comment: And that's really `if ( ["A", "B"].indexOf(el[0].textContent) == -1)`